# Debugging ncurses application with gdb

Tags: c, input, gdb, ncurses

I'm trying to debug my ncurses application, using gdb. I use *tty* command to redirect program's I/O to another terminal. Output works like a charm, but I'm having problems with input. I'm using getch() function to retrieve symbols in my app. So, for instance, if I do in my gdb session:

```
tty /dev/pts/5
```

I get my output in another tab of my terminal window (gnome-terminal). My gdb sessions is getting stuck, waiting for input, but when I press any key within my /dev/pts/5 I get it printed out, but the app itself does not except it as an input symbol. When running without gdb everything works fine, I'm also using noecho(), so symbols should not be displayed. 
So, what's the problem? Is it possible to somehow handle input from redirected terminal?

Comment: note that there is an example like this in the book http://www.amazon.com/The-Art-Debugging-GDB-Eclipse/dp/1593271743/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1345020329&sr=8-1&keywords=debug+gdb

Comment: Thank you. I've taken note of this book.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can attach to your process to debug from a different terminal instead of trying to run the application from within `gdb`.

Run your process as normal. When it is blocked for user input, find its process ID, and then attach to it with `gdb` from a different window:

```
gdb -p <PID>
```

Your problem is due to the program still expecting its interactive input to be coming from your `gdb` session.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. But still the problem is not solved. I got connected to my process. Then I hit *continue* in my gdb session and it got stuck -- I can work with my ncurses application, but can't with gdb.

Comment: @UgnichenkoDmitriy: You have to set a breakpoint, or interrupt the process in `gdb` with Ctrl-C.

Comment: Yep, it did help. I've loaded my symbols table with *file* and set my bp. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, for those, who can't connect with gdb to their process and running Ubuntu, you should echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope or make it permanent and set 0 in /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf

Comment: Another way to succeed in attaching gdb to the process is running gdb as root. This is proposed by GDB: `Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf`

Answer (score 9):

Maybe it's a bit late to answer, but hope this helps:
It took some time to figure out how to debug ncurses applications,
finally i made a very comfy way with the help of *gdbserver* and *tmux*.

This way I/O of gdb and the application are completely separated:

debug.sh (the script that starts debugging):

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux splitw -h -p 50 "gdbserver :12345 ./yourapplication"
tmux selectp -t 0
gdb -x debug.gdb
```

debug.gdb (one-liner gdb scriptfile for comfort):

```
target remote localhost:12345
```

So this way, application starts up on right side, gdb on left waiting to hit continue or any other usual gdb stuff :)

Once you exit, tmux automatically closes the gdbserver (therefore right panel as well) and that's all :)

Comment: (of course, the important is the gdbserver / gdb pair, tmux-part can be completely skipped, just sometimes it's easier to have them side-by-side without more terminals :D)

Comment: Nice script this is really great!