# CLion run program in separate system terminal

Tags: c++, debugging, terminal, ncurses, clion

I have an `ncurses` program that I'd like to interactively debug using CLion. The problem is that when I run the program in CLion to debug it, the inbuilt console where the program is run doesn't display the output of the `ncurses` program properly.

I'd like to have the program run in my systems terminal so I can see the output properly whilst debugging the program with CLions debugger.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a CLion program in gnome terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675012/how-to-execute-a-clion-program-in-gnome-terminal)

Comment: @VictorSergienko That question is newer.

Comment: @L.F. I believe that one has a better answer.

Comment: the answer in the other question does not allow for debugging, just running in a seperate terminal.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to accomplish this is to use GDB now it can be really frustrating to get started so Ill show you how I accomplished it in linux

1. open a terminal and go to your project debug file and type `gdbserver localhost:1234 ./myFile`
2. open clion to myFile project and in the upper right corner you should see a build all (or your projects name) click it and go to "edit configurations"
3. in the upper left corner you should see a plus sign, click it and press "GDB remote debug"
4. then in "target remote" type `tcp:127.0.0.1:1234`
5. Next in "path mappings" press the plus and type `/location/to/file/myFile` (same file as in 1.) in both Remote and Location
6. Press OK and in the upper right corner select the name of the configuration that you just made and press debug

you might need to try to restart the gdbserver one more time for this to work but if you did all the steps above you should see a debug prompt come up and on the terminal you should see your project running.

There are some limitations with this for example you always have to run `gdbserver localhost:1234 ./myFile` command on your terminal for it to work.

Some Video/documentation that helped me:

- [Debugging with GDB at 33:35 (Video by JetBrain)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2R3OSGmUmoU)
- [GDB documentation on Jetbrain](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/07/clion-2016-2-eap-remote-gdb-debug/)

I hope this helped :)

Comment: Is there anyway to attach the debugger to a process when it starts up? I'm having my `ncurses` project run in an xterm window at startup.

Comment: I recommend using port 2159, which is the official port for GDB remote debugging.

Answer (score 3):

In other debuggers, you would do this by running the `ncurses` application in a terminal, and *attaching* the debugger to the process using `ncurses`.

Doing that avoids interference between `ncurses` (which changes the terminal I/O modes) and the debugger's command-line.

The *attach* feature is a recently released feature of the CLions debugger:

Further reading:

- [More power to debug: Attach to local process](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/01/attach-to-local-process/) (January 20, 2016)
- [CLion 1.2 roadmap](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/08/clion-1-2-roadmap/) (August 31, 2015)
- [Debugging in CLion](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/05/debug-clion/) (May 8, 2015 )
- [CLion answers frequently asked questions](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/) (September 16, 2014)
- [Debugging ncurses application with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965328/debugging-ncurses-application-with-gdb)
- [Using GNU's GDB Debugger: 
  Debugging Ncurses Programs](http://dirac.org/linux/gdb/07-Debugging_Ncurses_Programs.php)