# Ncurses and gdb screens overlap at debug time. So I want to split the two screens with each other

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gdb, ncurses

I'm debugging a ncurses program using the gdb. when program run and reached the breakpoint and use cont command, ncurses program gui screen overlap a gdb screen, [like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbpac.png)

I'm sorry I can't show you the code because I had a situation.

Answer (score 1):

Both "own" the whole display.  You can work around this by running gdb in a different terminal, and attaching to the process which uses ncurses.

Further reading:

- [Debugging ncurses application with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965328/debugging-ncurses-application-with-gdb)